# Configure Jenkins to deploy PHP project that passed PHPUNit

Tags: jenkins, phpunit, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have PHP Project, that is hosted on GitHub. 
Now, I'd like to configure Jenkins to run unit tests so that:

- Whenever developer push/commits code to specific branch, it triggers corresponding PHPUnit build job.
- If commit passes the unit tests, the source code is deployed (assuming I already have the required script to deploy).

The question is how to trigger the deployment script when source code passes the unit test (i.e. PHPUnit tests succeed)?

Please suggest to me the way to do that, which plugin I should try to achieve the result?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a long post, as there's a lot involved, but it works a treat:

You will need:

- **Ant**
- **Git Publisher** plugin
- **Ant** and **phpunit** will need to be on your PATH

**Step 1: Configure your project**

In your Jenkins, configure your project to 'Poll SCM' under the Git option. Leave the 'Schedule' as blank. Under 'branches to build' set that as the branch you want to build your release package from.
Reference:

[image]

**Step 2: Run ant for every build**

Add a build step to 'Invoke Ant'

If you don't use Ant already, create a build.xml file in your project root, add it to Git and have the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project default="full-build">
<property name="phpunit" value="phpunit"/>

<target name="full-build"
      depends="phpunit-unittests,-check-failure"
      description="runs the tests"/>

<target name="phpunit-unittests"
      unless="phpunit-unittests.done"
      description="Run unit tests with PHPUnit">
    <exec executable="cmd" failonerror="true" resultproperty="result.phpunit" taskname="phpunit-unittests">
    <arg value="/c"/>
    <arg value="${phpunit}"/>
    <arg value="--configuration"/>
   <arg path="${basedir}/phpunit.xml"/>
     <arg value="--testsuite=Unit"/>
  </exec>

  <property name="phpunit-unittests.done" value="true"/>
</target>

<target name="-check-failure">
    <fail message="PHPUnit did not finish successfully">
    <condition>
    <not>
      <equals arg1="${result.phpunit}" arg2="0"/>
    </not>
    </condition>
    </fail>
</target>
</project>
```

That will run all unit tests whenever the Ant task is invoked, which is now set for every time the project is built.

Then, install the **Git Publisher** tool. Configure as follows:

[image]

This creates a new release tag upon a successful build. You will use this later to publish the release to the final location. **Note:** There are different variables that Git Publisher provides for use, commit hash, user etc so use what you want. I stick to an incremental tag of v1.1.BUILD as that's a bit more standard.

Lastly, you will need to add a Git hook which will trigger a build upon a commit/push from any location.

Navigate to your repository folder and within that the **'`hooks`'** directory.
Create a new file named 'post-receive' (you will see examples in there; overwrite this one). Place the following content in:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read oldrev newrev refname
do
    branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $refname)
    if [ "master" == "$branch" ]; then
        curl http://YOUR_JENKINS_URL:8080/git/notifyCommit?url=YOUR_GIT_REPOSITORY_URL
    fi
done
```

That should do the job nicely. I have left out implementation details of how you actually release your project as everyone does this differently. There are options to FTP files to a location, and all sorts. Personally I go into the folder where the application resides and do a checkout of the newly created tag - a one line command. Whatever suits your environment.

Other stuff I've ommitted but you will find useful - the Ant build task can do literally anything - In mine, I run composer to install dependences, run bower, run grunt, do syntax checking, coding standard checking, fire up selenium and run web tests, and a load of other stuff. It's a perfect combination of tools to automate the whole project deployment.